# Chrome extension custom payment solution in Pakistan?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, payment-gateway, chrome-web-store, google-account, merchant-account

I have been trying to add payment module in my chrome extension. It came to me that my region Pakistan is not supported for chrome in-app Payment service.
Also i am unable to create Google merchant account.
it gives me error

```
Your country Pakistan is unsupported for this merchant.
```

Any suggestions which payment method and how to use it to charge for my chrome extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Supported locations for developer & merchant registration](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3539140?hl=en), your country Pakistan is supported and it has a Google Play Distributor of Google Asia Pacific Limited. Also from this [page](https://propakistani.pk/2014/11/08/google-adds-pakistan-list-supported-countries-play-store-merchant-accounts/), 2 years ago the Pakistan is included to the list of countries where publishers are allowed to have merchant accounts to accept payments for their premium apps and in-app purchases.

You can check this page, [Set up Google Apps billing and payments](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2633430?hl=en) to know how to setup your Google Apps for payment. Just follow the instruction from 1 to 8.

You can also check on this page the **Questions** part that have a question, **What if my country isn't listed when I try to add my billing address?**

In some countries, the billing address you specify for a payment method must be in the same country as the billing country you select when you set up your Google billing account. If that's true for your location, you can't enter any other country in a billing address. Nor can you change the billing country associated with your account.

If your billing address isn't in the country you selected for your billing account, you can:

- Add a new payment method with a billing address that is in your billing account's country.
- Transfer your account to one of our [Google Apps partners](http://www.google.com/a/partnersearch/#home) who might be able to change your billing account's country for you.

Comment: Thanx I'll try it out.

Comment: Now that i have created merchant account and payment account for google i need to set up account from this url 
https://payments.google.com/merchant/signup
as described by chrome extension tutorials
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap#setup-account
 which is not accessible right now.